# Where/how to add custom js magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I made a magento module, and I need to add some custom javascript.

I put the following in my layout file (and it's working, with my custom js places in /js/):

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>my_custom_js.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

My question is - where is the best place for these files, in `/js/jquery/` or in `/skin/frontend/default/default/js`? If I put it in default/default, how do I reference it from the XML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is required for your module (critical functionality):

```
/js/[namespace]/[module]/
```

If it is required for a theme (UI enhancement):

```
/skin/frontend/[group]/[theme]/js/
```

Comment: How about CSS that is required as critical functionality ?

Comment: How is that even possible? Your module might come with default CSS (which goes into the `base/default` theme) but CSS is not tightly coupled to functionality.

Comment: well, my module creates some custom pop-ups, so the css for the containers is critical, or else things will start to look very badly. I worded my comment badly, sorry

Comment: I'd say, that is critical, but not functionally critical, because as you said, thinks will just *look* bad. So, to clarify: `skin/frontend/base/default/css/[module]/` is the way to go.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler would you say a Javascript package such as OwlCarousel is best saved to `/js/[namespace]/[module]/` as opposed to `/skin/frontend/[group]/[theme]/js/`?

Comment: @LiamMcArthur no, if you need it for the theme, I'd put it into `skin`